# How to call Activity from PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, android-activity, preferences

I need to launch new Activity from PreferenceActivity on button click or somehow else. Is it possible? How to make it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can start another `Activity` from your `PreferenceActivity` like the standard way of doing that. For example:

```
Intent testIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
startActivity(testIntent);
```

First, define a Preference in your XML:

```
<Preference
    android:key="test_pref"
    android:summary="@string/someDescription"
    android:title="Some Random Title" >
</Preference>
```

In your `PreferenceActivity`:

```
Preference pref = findPreference("test_pref");
shareSociallyYou.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

        Intent testIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
        startActivity(testIntent);

        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
Preference preference = findPreference("Your Preference Key");
    preference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

This should be in the oncreate or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the intent as preference action in XML as well. Just add to your preference XML:

```
<PreferenceScreen android:key="KEY" android:title="DOYOURWORK">
    <intent android:targetClass="com.yourcompany.app.youractivity"
        android: targetPackage="com.yourcompany.app">
        <extra android:name="EXTRA_KEY" android:value="yourValue" />
    </intent>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

and now the tricky part i wanted to share:
The xml attribute `android:targetPackage` in the `<intent>` node refers to your application package, **NOT THE JAVA PACKAGE!**
So as long as you work within your app and not calling external intents, you just have to state your application package no matter in which **JAVA** package the activity class is located in your application project.

I hope this helps, i couldn't find any documentation on this stuff, just user postings in the web.